# Cannot install banshee due to unmet dependencies

Tags: banshee

I am trying to install Banshee from the Ubuntu Software Center after installing VLC and Clementine, but I'm running into errors:

[image]

I tried installing from terminal but got this:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 banshee : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.32.3) but 2.32.1-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Recommends: banshee-extension-soundmenu (= 2.4.1-3ubuntu1~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you added any PPAs to your software sources? Is this a clean installation of Ubuntu 12.04, or did you upgrade from a previous version?

Comment: It is clean installation of ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install banshee`? The `-f` argument should install all dependencies required, along with the actual program (that's important). It's weird that the dependencies in a .deb didn't install.

If that does not work, you should probably check and see what repositories you have (open up software center, go to edit, then go to software sources). You should have a few in there, and make sure the correct fields are checked.

It is important that Canonical is selected.

Comment: The dependencies won't install.  Take a look at the errors, its looking for *newer* software versions than are available on the system.  For most of the deps, at least.  For the others, the ones throwing the errors where it needs newer versions but there is a valid version are probably depending on those which need a newer version which does not exist on the system.

Comment: Ahh kk, I couldn't see the text in the snapshot well, so I assumed it just wasn't installing the dependencies along with the main package which was causing the main error. I wonder if they are available to the system, but the repository is messed up.

Comment: You can try my method, but from what Lord of Time has said, it may not work as the system is looking for newer software versions. I was able to install banshee, but this was a fresh install, and all the repos are in. You should probably check and see what repositories you have (open up software center, go to edit, then go to software sources). You should have a few in there, and make sure the correct fields are checked.

Comment: Hey compt your solution worked. "Canonical Partners" wasn't checked in software sources.

Comment: That's good :D. In 11.10, I had a problem where nothing was ever updating. Turns out it somehow became unchecked. Suffice to say, it's small things like a check box that can make a huge difference lol.

Comment: So we're clear, the correct solution was enabling "Canonical Partners" in the software sources?  If so, it would be best if this answer was updated to include that. No one wants good info to get buried in the comments. :)

Comment: Good idea, I'll edit that in.